# Ace Editor in PHP Web App

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I am making a small web app that allows users to submit html, css and javascript content via [Ace Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/). In this editor, echoing stored content into the editor is simply enough however I cannot find anyway to submit a users input to the database. I can see there is a textarea generated by the JavaScript however I'm not exactly sure what it is doing, how to get to it or if I should be looking for something else entirely.

I'm primarily looking for a field or something that I can use to have php submit into the db.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The contents of the edit window are available with the session getValue method.  For example, here is an extension to the standard ACE demo for save file:

```
saveFile = function() {
    var contents = env.editor.getSession().getValue();

    $.post("write.php", 
            {contents: contents },
            function() {
                    // add error checking
                    alert('successful save');
            }
    );
};
```

I added the saveFile call to the already existing "Fake Save" that is in demo.js. I replace the alert with code like this:

```
// Fake-Save, works from the editor and the command line.
canon.addCommand({
    name: "save",
    bindKey: {
        win: "Ctrl-S",
        mac: "Command-S",
        sender: "editor|cli"
    },
    exec: function() {
        saveFile();
    }
});
```

The php file is just one line:

`$r = file_put_contents("foo.txt", $_POST["contents"]) or die("can't open file");`

Comment: that is bloody brilliant. Thank you. I have three editors on the same page so I can already see how I can use the AJAX post code you have provided to differentiate them.

`var htmlContents = env.htmlEditor.getSession().getValue();
var cssContents = env.cssEditor.getSession().getValue();
var jsContents = env.jsEditor.getSession().getValue();`

Obviously I'd have to also change the content: contents section too.
Thank you, you are AWESOME!

Comment: Hi @Paul, Is there a way to do this without an AJAX Post?

Comment: @Dave - I don't know. Perhaps, try the ACE forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ace-discuss