# How do I take the content of the Ace code editor with a laravel form

Tags: javascript, laravel

as the question says, I want to submit the code from the editor,but I don't know how can I do this using a laravel form. I found that I can use `editor.getValue()` [here](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto) but don't know how to use it with laravel. I have the following code

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        right: 150px;
        bottom: 150px;
        left: 150px;
    }
    .ace_editor {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        margin: auto;
        height: 65%;
        width: 55%;
    }
    .scrollmargin {
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProblemsController@store']) !!}
  <div id="editor">
    //Your code goes here
  </div>
  {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
      editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
      editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
  </script>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden input and filled with `editor.getValue()` in onchange method. something like this:

Javascript

```
editor.session.on('change', function(delta) {
   var content=document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
   content.value=editor.getValue()
});
```

HTML

```
 <input name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput">
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working, but is it secure? I asked for an approach like ```{{Form::textarea}}``` or something like that, but is ok if it's safe.

Comment: Yes, is secure. You can use this type of declaration if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314789/insert-a-value-to-hidden-input-laravel-blade
greatings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` session event to update a hidden textarea field with contents of the Ace editor (untested code following):

**JavaScript:**

```
const $formElement = $('.js-ace-code');

editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    $formElement.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
```

Add a additional textarea to your desired form in which the Ace editor resides:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="code" class="js-ace-code" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</form>
```

There's apparently also a method where you can [add a button with a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659559) to update the code via an AJAX request.